# Conditional Pandas Statement and Apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can't share a lot of my code, but I'm using a conditional statement to then pass a function to a column in my dataframe. I'm getting a Database error `(<cx_Oracle._Error object at 0x00000114A0BE38D0>`, `'occurred at index 880')`.

```
def my_new_func(row):
    return RCCheck.nsamcheck(
        sk=row['sk'], reportseries=row['reportseries'], rssd=row['rssd'], username=username, pw=password)


NSAM.loc[(NSAM['Security_Description']=='Update External User - Reporting') & (NSAM.Analyst.isin(analyst_list)), 'Action'] = NSAM.apply(my_new_func, axis=1)
```

The error message indicates there is a problem at index 880, which is the first row of my dataframe, but does not have the conditions expressed in my Boolean indexing above. My question is why is it applying the function to my entire data frame as opposed to those I am filtering for?

Comment: I think we’re going to need more information than this.

Comment: I know the amount of information isn't ideal, I'm sharing what I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
NSAM['Action'] = NSAM.loc[(NSAM['Security_Description'] == 'Update External User - Reporting') & (NSAM.Analyst.isin(analyst_list))].apply(my_new_func, axis=1)
```

In my original code I said NSAM.apply(my_new_func, axis =1). I was calling the whole dataframe to apply the function to, not the filtered version.